# How to pass data from view to UserControl in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, user-controls, viewusercontrol

Say I want to do the simplest of the data passing as follows :

```
<% For i = 0 To 10%>
    <%Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl")%>
<% Next%>
```

What I want to do is to pass the variable i as the parameter to the UserControl so that it displays the number inside a, say, bordered div.

How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% For i = 0 To 10%> 
    <%Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl", i)%> 
<% Next%>
```

The RenderPartial method has an overload that allows you to pass in a (sub)model. To use it most effectively, your UserControl should be strongly typed - in this case to a model of type System.Int32.

---

To use it in a UserControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Int32>" %>
<div><%= this.Html.Encode(this.Model) %></div>
```

In this case, `this.Model` is a System.Int32 instance.

Comment: How would I use it on the UserControl?

Answer (score -2):

- you do not. This stuff must be in the model, suppsedly.
- PLease upgrade to MVC v2 ;) get rid of the strings.

Comment: At the very least you should provide examples on how to get rid of the strings.